# Inno setup UninstallRun and interactive process

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup, if in the section [UninstallRun] I launch a non-interactive .exe, it works. But if I launch an interactive .exe (mini VB.Net application which asks through a form the reasons of the uninstallation for sending on my site), this .exe loops and the continuation of the uninstallation is not done.
Is it possible to do that or does it need a particular parameter?

Inno Setup Compiler v6.0.2
Windows 11

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents You should write some Pascal script to launch your executable in `InitializeUninstall`. That's where people usually ask for user input.

Comment: When I click on the Quit button on the form, the form processes the information and the mini application ends.
But the form reappears and so on.

Comment: The log is too long. How to join a file?

Comment: Thank for then link! I think my problem is solved by adding RunOnceId: "Uninstall" to the line.